# set state of specific attribute inside of an object

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling to figure out the syntax for setting the state of an object inside of an array. I'm trying to access the fruits amount attribute. I'm familiar with concat for adding a new object and such but instead of adding a new updated object, how do I replace the value of an attribute inside of an object keeping everything the same except the attribute that changed and not adding a completely new object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import Fruits from'./Fruits';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      fruits: [
        {
          type:'apple',
          amount:10,
          color:'green',
          id: 0
        },
        {
          type:'tomato',
          amount:'25',
          color:'red',
          id: 1
        }
      ]
    };
  }
renderFruits = () => {
  const { fruits } = this.state;
    return fruits.map((item, index) =>
      <Fruits
        key={index}
          type={item.type}
            amount={item.amount}
              color={item.color}
                id={item.id}
                  increment={this.increment}
       />
        );
  }

  increment = (fruitId) => {
    const { fruits } = this.state;
    const incrementedFruit = fruits.filter((item) => {
      return item.id == fruitId;
    })
    //{fruits: {...fruits, [fruits.amount]: [fruits.amount++]}}
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <div>
          {this.renderFruits()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Fruits Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Fruits extends Component {

increment = () => {
  const { id } = this.props;
  this.props.increment(id);
}

decrement = () => {
  console.log("decremented");
}


  render() {
    const { type, id, amount, color} = this.props;
    return(
      <div>
       <span>
         {type}
          <ul>
            <li>amount: {amount} </li>
            <li>color: {color} </li>
          </ul>
          <button onClick={this.increment}> + </button>
          <button onClick={this.decrement}> - </button>
       </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Fruits;
```

[stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/increment-inside-of-array-of-objects?embed=1&file=Fruits.js)

Comment: You want to increase the value of `amount` of just one fruit right ?

Comment: thats correct in the increment method in App I'm trying to increment the amount for the specific fruit clicked thats why I pass the id into Fruits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pass `index` from fruit, lets take as `index` prop :

```
<Fruits
    key={item.id}
    index = {index}
    type={item.type}
    amount={item.amount}
    color={item.color}
    id={item.id}
    increment={this.increment}
  />
```

Then pass index, instead of id of fruit on increment :

```
increment = () => {
  this.props.increment(this.props.index);
}
```

You can make your increment function 2 ways  :

**1 : with state mutation** , Please read : [State Mutation](https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c)

```
  increment = (index) => {
    ++this.state.fruits[index].amount;

    this.forceUpdate();
    //OR
    this.setState({fruits : this.state.fruits});
  }
```

**2 : without state mutation**

```
  increment = (index) => {
    let fruits = this.state.fruits.slice();
    ++fruits[index].amount;
    this.setState({fruits});
  }
```

> P.S: Also found that you are using the array index as key. This is
>   deprecated. See
>   https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318
>
> So also change :
>
> from `key={index}` to `key={item.id}`

Comment: You are mutating the state directly

Comment: @Dane, Thanks for pointing out, I have updated answer for both case.

Comment: How does index automatically adjust to what index the object is in the array? I know it works but I never really understood how.

Comment: It is the 2nd argument to the callback function `Array.map`

Comment: Okay thats good now I can see why we do not even need the fruitId simply rely on the callback of Array.map. @Dane

Comment: @VivekDoshi whats the benefits or cons of the first increment method vs the second does it even matter?

Comment: @Omar , please read : https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c

Answer (score 1):

just change your increment function to this:

```
  increment = (fruitId) => {
    const { fruits } = this.state;
    fruits.forEach((fruit)=>{
      if(fruit.id == fruitId){
         fruit.amount = parseInt(fruit.amount)+ 1;
      }
    })
    this.setState({fruits: fruits})
  }
```

Edited

Comment: This seems a bit clunky but this is kind of what I was looking for opposed to the other answer. I'm not really sure what the better implementation is.

Comment: @Omar, so you will loop through each fruits , on single increment , fruits.forEach? This what you looking for ?

Comment: No this is not exactly what I'm looking for. What I was looking for was a way to increment the amount just based off knowing the id of the fruit clicked. He still used fruitId instead you used index. Your implementation is much cleaner!!